# np.squeeze what means axis=-1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

The [numpy.squeeze](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) function takes an `axis` parameter which should be an integer. Sometimes I see the axis parameter being set to `axis=-1`, however the documentation does not explain what a negative integer does in this case.

What does numpy.squeeze do exactly when `axis=-1` is set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Playing around with it I could observe the following. The axis parameter selects which dimension of the array should be affected by the squeeze.
For example:

```
x = np.array([[[0], [1], [2]]])
x.shape
```

> (1,3,1)

the array `x` is three dimensional with 1 entry in first dimension 3 entries in second dimension and 1 entry in third dimension. Selecting `axis=-1` causes the last dimension to be affected by the squeeze:

```
np.squeeze(x, axis=-1).shape
```

> (1, 3)

So basically, it flattens out the selected dimension to the level above, but only if the selected dimension has length 1. If it is longer, an error is returned.

Comment: Often we use `squeeze` to remove all size 1 dimensions.  The `axis` parameter lets us choose which ones we want to remove.  '-1' has the usual 'last' dimension meaning.

Comment: My impression is that once you start using the axis parameter here, you have enough information about that shape that you could just as easily use `reshape`.  I'd put more effort into understanding and using `reshape` and indexing, reserving `squeeze` for when their use is too messy.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, the axis parameter

> Selects a subset of the single-dimensional entries in the shape.

Basically you choose along which axis you want to apply `squeeze`.

Eg

```
a = numpy.ones((1,2,2,1))
a.shape

(1,2,2,1)

numpy.squeeze(a,axis=0).shape

(2,2,1)

numpy.squeeze(a,axis=-1).shape

(1,2,2)
```

So `axis=-1` chooses the last axis by numpy convention

If the size of the last axis is more than one, it raises an error.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, squeeze simply removes axes of length one from the array.

you can specify the axis to remove:

```
x = np.array([[[0], [1], [2]]])
x.shape
(1, 3, 1)

np.squeeze(x, axis=0).shape
(3, 1)
```

or not, where it will remove all axes with length One:

```
np.squeeze(x).shape
(3,)
```